# How to get around query string truncation in MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, firefox, query-string

I have an application that allows a user to have up to 255 characters in their username, including special characters. What's happening is when I run the code, the query string being passed to the method is getting truncated, so the logic in the method doesn't get the full username, only the truncated one, this results in the method returning a null user object and I end up with the null reference exception. IE seems to not have this issue, only with FF and Chrome. For question purposes and testing, this is the username that is being truncated:

> testuser3743804!@#$%^&()-_+=|/?.'~gsdgsdjsfjdhfdjhfdjsjlkajdlajladskashdasndkjahdjkashdjkasdhjkashdjkashdjkahdjkadhajkdhajksdhjkahdjkashdkashdkashdjkahdiyeiyqwkhjkdnsdasjkdhqwuieyqwieyishdjkashdkdjkahdjkadjkadjkahdjikadhjuiuiuha734634823682688274@test.tst

In FF and Chrome, when debugging, they both only encode the query string parameter up to this portion of the username: `testuser3743804!@#$%^&()-_+=|/?.`

That is all that's sent back to the method, which is why i keep getting the null reference exception. Is there a way to "force" the whole thing to be sent through FF and Chrome so I don't run into this problem?

Comment: How is that username being submitted?

Comment: Are you posting that in a form?

Comment: The username is being looked up based on a id number being searched for, then passed as a query string parameter, in HTTPfox, the querystring reads like this: username=testuser3743804!%40%23%24%25%5E%26()-_%2B%3D%7C%2F%3F.&    --- Not sure why it's stopping after the ".", if you look at the full username, it's getting truncated after the .

Comment: It's stopping after the `.` because the next character is `&`, and that should be URL encoded.

Comment: If you look at the full username I posted originally, there is an & sign in there that is being encoded properly when looking at the query string through httpfox. And the place you are talking about in the full username, there is no & sign after the period, only a ' mark.

Comment: Hmmm... you're right. I wonder if the ' has any impact there...

Comment: from what i understand, the "'" is not a system reserved character and wouldn't have to be url encoded...

Comment: So here's the deal, I'm not the original creator of this app. And here's what I did to alleviate this issue. Since it's really a security concern to be passing a username in the url anyways, I changed it to pass a UserGuid instead, plus point at a different method that works the proper way. I have it all working right now.